# Which is better separating big data into 2 tables or collect it all in one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a web app that has a big load of data for its items. I was wondering if separating the data into 2 tables (ItemData & ItemDataDetails) would decrease the execution time of the queries. 
My drive is that I have 2 pages, 1 page which displays the most basic info regarding the item and another that shows the details. By logic I think that it should decrease the load time for the page where the basic info is showed. Am I correct or not?

Comment: Do you mean that there are a lot of rows in the table, or do you mean that you are grabing a large amount of data for display in html?

Comment: Large amounts of data. My table currently has 40 required fields and more not required. During the initial pull I don't need all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that retrieving less data will generally be faster than retrieving more.
That said, the process of separating / isolating data (into different tables based on the  relationship between items of data) as a means of reducing redundancy & dependency to which you refer is known as database normalization and is a well accepted and documented best practice.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Actually if the relationship is 1 - 1, this would be a de-normalisation

Comment: @TonyHopkinson your comment made me think a little more - I don't think OP is actually normalizing or denormalizing. 
No redundancies are being resolved or reintroduced. 
It's plain optimization. Would you agree?

Comment: Normalisation and denormalisation are optimisations. In that you have two tables keyed by the same value, where one would do, this is a de-normalisation. Think of it this way, there's a diffrence between unnormalised and denormalised. Any optimsation in favour of one factor is always an un-optimisation of another.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson my view is that recombining these tables would _also_ be a denormalization under that logic. 
How can two opposing actions both be denormalization?

Comment: both can be identified by the same key, so normalisation would suggest they should be in the same table so I'd see recombining them as an optimisation to reduce footprint and complexity with a concommittant de-optimisation in terms row sizing etc. No biggy, 1-1s are too useful to go purist.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost certainly correct in this case given you are talking say show some "header" / summary data for 1 item on one page and  then all details for that one item on another. Especially if the user isn't definitely going to want to view the detail. Be wary of this idea, with a list, or when you want to display summary and detail on one page.